# Sharing data through an android app on different user

Tags: android

I want to share some data(query results from sqlite db) through my app installed by different users.May be export from the app in some format and share it and import that in the app by other user.
Please let me know which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can some one please give an answer for this?

Comment: AFAIK, to archive it, you must store your data in your server.

Comment: Sorry what you mean by AFAIK?

Comment: For the time being I am not planning to have a backend serevr.I am planning to create own format and snad use any file sharing mechanism.I need to try out this.But is there any good approach?